# Facebook comment plugin for website and registered users

Tags: facebook, comments, registration

I'm using Facebook registration for my website and I'm also using Facebook comments plugin on several pages on my website. I want to only allow registered users to comment. I don't want to simply hide the comments if they're not registered. I want them to see the comments but only be allowed to add comments if they are registered. Any ideas?

Comment: I found it that facebook will attempt to crawl the URL with their bot if you add their sdk, if the webpage is only available for registered users this will block the facebook bot and the webpage preview in facebook will show a snippet "Page not found"

Answer (score 0):

If the user is registered, show the comment plugin like normal.  If they aren't registered, you could use the graph api (https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.example.com) to pull the comments and render them yourself and style them to look similar to the Facebook plugin.